# best DS to insert and delete values?

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist

I have a scenario where I have a class that's a listener to a server. When I am notified I keep adding a string of values to an `ArrayList`. I now have threads that read from this `ArrayList`.

This `ArrayList` has the potential of becoming very large. I'm thinking of spawning a thread that checks every 10 mins if the max size has been reached and deletes a few lines that were added.

I was wondering what is the best way to achieve this?

Should I be using another DS?

Comment: If I were you, instead of coming up with my own algorithms of data removal, I'd stick to an implementation of Queue. Check them out and see if they fit your needs.

Comment: You saying you wish to just discard some entries if you become full, suggests you should look into using a circular queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

```
                 ArrayList    LinkedList
add                O(1)*         O(1)
remove             O(n)          O(n)
Iterator.remove    O(n)          O(1)
insert             O(n)          O(1)
get                O(1)          O(n)
```

* `ArrayList.add` runs in O(n) worst case if the array needs to be resized.